# What code and how does java.lang.reflect.Array create a new array at runtime?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I looked into Java source code and the method is like follows:

```
public static Object newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int length)
    throws NegativeArraySizeException {
    return newArray(componentType, length);
}

private static native Object newArray(Class componentType, int length)
    throws NegativeArraySizeException;
```

It seems it does not have any code in the method `newArray()` to build an array. Can anyone explain how it builds an array? T

Comment: It's pretty much hardcoded into Java, or in other words, it uses black magic.

Comment: `native` methods delegate to C code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a `native` method.

That means it's implemented by native code within the JRE.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard-coded into the JVM (not the compiler). You could download the source code of OpenJDK or any other open-source Java Virtual Machine and look there ;)

Comment: Any idea where to look?

Comment: Start here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/9b6070690e50/src/share/native/java/lang/reflect/Array.c

Comment: Then go here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp - at this point, you should realize that this is intimately connected to the JVM internals and there's really no point in trying to understand the code.

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/bb416ee2a79b/src/share/vm/runtime/reflection.cpp line 319

Comment: @Esailija http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/runtime/reflection.cpp