# Why most of the java.lang.reflect.Array class methods are 'native'

Tags: java, jvm

I have gone through [What code and how does java.lang.reflect.Array create a new array at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817184/what-code-and-how-does-java-lang-reflect-array-create-a-new-array-at-runtime),. I understand that they are implemented in native language ('C'), But my question is why almost all methods java.lang.reflect.Array class methods are *native* .

My guess and understanding is that

- To improve performance ? or to allocate continuous memory for arrays by JVM ?

Is my understanding correct about native methods in Array class or Do i miss anything ?

Comment: What would be the alternative to having them make native calls exactly?

Comment: They're implemented in native code because there's no way to implement them in non-native code.

Comment: I don't know. That is that reason asking right ?. I tried to find reasons and I found only those pints, but not confident. I need some more clarity.

Comment: Thanks Louis, but why not possible to implement in non-native language ?

Comment: @Jayasagar: I don't know how to answer that question.  Those functions can't be implemented in pure Java because if you try it, you won't be able to.

Comment: @user2864740: Sure, for just the primitive types, but you can't list all the non-primitive types, and you can't just say `(String[]) new Object[length]`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yeah, I realized such (as I edited my later comment) - care to expand on it in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are at the heart of all multi-valued data structures. Arrays require using segments of memory on the host machine, which means accessing memory in a safe, and machine specific manner - that requires calls to the underlying operating system.

Such calls are `native` because to perform them you must move out of java and into the host environment to complete them. At *some* point every operation must be handed over to the host machine to actually implement it using the local OS and hardware.

Comment: I'm not buying this. Why *couldn't* one use a switch to `new primitiveTypeOrObject[length]`? I think the answer comes from the implementation of `new T[]`, for an arbitrary `T` (that is *not* caught in a generic type parameter).. but *not* because of the "must move out of Java" reason. After all, I can `int[] x = new int[0]` no problem without needing to do anything native.

Comment: @user2864740: that's exactly correct; the issue is the implementation of `new T[]`.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemain. I understood much better now :).

Comment: @user2864740 `int[] x = new int[0]` is an edge case: Any decent compiler would bypass the call to the native method that allocates memory in this instance.

Comment: @Bohemian It doesn't matter. As shown, since I can create a new array *in plain Java* (which ultimately ends up in bytecode and whatever the JVM does), why does the code shown use native calls? That is, I am asserting that *the basis for this answer is wrong* with respect to the question.

Answer (score 4):

The [`reflect.Array.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) method uses native code because it *must* use native code. This has nothing inherently to do with performance but is a result of the fact that the Java language *cannot* express this operation.

To show that it's a *language limitation* and not strictly related to performance, here is some valid code which creates a new array without directly invoking any native method.

```
Object x = new String[0];
```

However, `newInstance` takes an *arbitrary value* of `Class<?>` and then creates the corresponding array with the represented type. However, this construct is *not* possible in plain Java and it cannot be expressed by the type-system or corresponding normal "new array" syntax.

```
// This production is NOT VALID in Java, as T is not a type
// (T is variable that evaluates to an object representing a type)
Class<?> T = String.class;
Object x = new T[0];

// -> error: cannot find symbol T
```

Because such a production is not allowed, a native method (which has access to the JVM internals) is used to create the new array instance of the corresponding type.

---

While the above argues for the case of `newInstance` needing to be native, I believe many of the other `reflect.Array` methods (which are get/set methods) *could* be handled in plain Java with the use of specialized casting; in these cases the argument for performance holds sway.

However, *most code does not use the Array reflection* (this includes "multi-valued data structures" such as [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)), but simply uses normal Java array access which is directly translated to the appropriate [Java bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) *without* going through `reflect.Array` or the native methods it uses.

---

Conclusion:

- Java *already* provides fast array access through the [JVM's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) execution of the [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode). [HotSpot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot), the "official" JVM, is written in C++ which is "native" code - but this execution of array-related bytecode is *independent* of `reflect.Array` and the use native methods.
- `newInstance` uses a native method because it *must* use a native method or otherwise [dynamically generate and execute bytecode](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).
- Other `reflect.Array` methods that *could* be expressed in Java are native methods for a combination of performance, dispatch simplicity, and "why not" - it's just as easy to add a second or third native method.